# Harry Potter fan fiction where Hermione leaves Draco on their wedding day

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, dramione

I read this fan fiction on fanfiction.net.

In the first book, Hermione and Draco fall in love and on Draco and Hermione's wedding day, the supposedly dead Lucius arrives with two other supposedly dead Death Eaters. Hermione decides to leave Draco that day.

In the sequel, Hermione and Draco have broken up and Hermione has a new fiance. The sequel begins with Hermione in a bar with her fiance. Draco then arrives coincidentally.

Comment: When did you read this? Any other possible details you can remember at all? Even if it's just a random scene that sticks out to you? something unique perhaps?